# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Philosophy Stack Exchange](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [In the following is Hobbes paraphrasing Aristotle?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/in-the-following-is-hobbes-paraphrasing-aristotle)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How can one in principle distinguish causality from observed regularity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/how-can-one-in-principle-distinguish-causality-from-observed-regularity)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Are electron fields physically real?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/are-electron-fields-physically-real)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [Is "Mickey Mouse" a rigid designator?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/is-mickey-mouse-a-rigid-designator)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Is modern information technology fundamentally changing the way humans acquire and process knowledge?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/is-modern-information-technology-fundamentally-changing-the-way-humans-acquire-a)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Ethical approach to the knowledge of suicide](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6932/ethical-approach-to-the-knowledge-of-suicide)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [How do we understand something?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/how-do-we-understand-something)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Are simple physical laws actually simple?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7055/are-simple-physical-laws-actually-simple)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [What makes a computer artificially intelligent?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/what-makes-a-computer-artificially-intelligent)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Are your actions for every type of determinism determined before your birth?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6935/are-your-actions-for-every-type-of-determinism-determined-before-your-birth)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 7)

Comment: Well, I guess we think the site "needs improvement"?

Comment: I think some of this might be a case of judging somewhat older questions by maybe newer standards. But I don't want to minimize; there's definitely a lot of opportunities for improvement!